# How to validate client is capable of using IPv6 addresses via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, ipv6

Wondering if there is a short and easy way to asynchronously look-up whether a user is IPv6 capable?  My current idea would be to attempt to download some resource from an IPv6-only website, but I'm unaware if any such websites exist.  Is there any way I can check this without relying on another website?

Comment: Relevant: http://ipv6test.google.com/

Comment: http://test-ipv6.com/ is open source but I'm not sure if you can use their API endpoints from another domain.

Comment: @Will I actually looked at that site and a few others but was unable to find an API on any of them sadly.

Comment: You could get an IPv6 address for your own site, and have the application check whether it can load from that address.

Comment: @Barmar That's a good idea, but until I actually own an IPv6 address for the site I can't get a working script to use before deployment.

Comment: @SethLarson Let it run the test, go to "Tests Run" and then "technical info" to see the URLs. Again, it's an [open source project](https://github.com/falling-sky/source/wiki) so you could run it on your own server but I didn't see anything using test-ipv6.com endpoint directly. I'd ask.

Comment: @Will It doesn't help to run it on his own server unless he has an IPv6 address for his server.

Comment: @barmar right. Was trying to point out the difference between using the code and using their server's API endpoints.